# Are R6 objects compatible with parallels package?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, r6

I'm thinking about leaving the S4 approach of R on OOP alone and I want to try using OOP with the newer R6 Package.
Now I want to know: Are the objects I am building using the package R6 compatible with the "parallel" package?
Thank you all.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: This question looks more a tweet than a SO question.

Comment: I'm asking only if the R6 package is compatible with the "parallel" package :)

Comment: Why not try it and let us know if you get stuck?